# Zero Divisor Rings

Tags: number-theory, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring, and let $a,b \in R$ such that $ab \ne 0$. Show that $ab$ is a zero divisor if and only if $a$ is a zero divisor or $b$ is a zero divisor.

I understand that a zero divisor is $ab = 0$ and that a zero divisor cannot be a unit in $R$ but I am not sure how to formulate the proof.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Is $R$ commutative?

If $a$ is a zero divisor, then $ac = 0$ for some $c$. Show that $ab$ is a zero divisor (and in fact that $abc = 0$). Likewise, if $b$ is a zero divisor.

If $a$ and $b$ are not zero divisors, then $abc = 0$ is a little worrying, because $bc$ can't be zero unless $c=0$ ($b$ is not a zero divisor), and $ax$ can't be zero for any non-zero $x$, including $x = bc$.

Answer (score 1):

$$ab\;\;\text{is a zero divisor}\iff \exists r\in R\;\;s.t.\;\;abr=0\,\,\vee\;rab=0\iff a(br)=0\,\,\vee (ra)b=0\ldots$$

Comment: Can you explain this answer? I am trying to understand how to formulate the proof, not be given the final answer.

Comment: If I explain I then give the final answer...:) , but whatever: putting for example $\,z:=br\,$, the above rightmost part is $az=0\,$ ....what does this tell you about $\,a\,$?

Comment: I still dont understand your initial answer. What is s.t.?

Comment: What I am getting from your initial answer is that $ab$ is a zero divisor iff there exists an $r$ in $R$ where $abr = 0$ or $rab = 0$ iff $a(br) = 0$ or $(ra)b = 0$. I understand that multiplication is commutative but shouldnt a proof go into more detail?

Comment: (1) s.t. = such that , (2) Of course the proof *must* go into more detail, but that's for you to complete, (3) if the ring's commutative then it is easier: $\,abr=arb=rab=0\,$ , and (4) mine was an answer-hint, as I most times try to give, not a compelte answer.